Google Cloud Build - unable to push artifacts to gs://
I am hoping to be able to run CI with my GitHub repository on Google Cloud Build. I have other repositories that are more basic  than this test, which work as expected, that is, the tests complete and build artifacts are correctly uploaded to Google Storage.
This build is a bit more challenging. Everything appears to work correctly, tests all run successfully, but I the artifacts don't appear to be generated, or at least not generated where the logs say they should be.
The error is Step #3: CommandException: No URLs matched: /tmp/lib.
The cloudbuild.yml file:
steps:
  # Build configuration
  - name: 'us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/github-test-builds-419921/ooctest/vulkan-loader-image:latest'
    entrypoint: '/bin/bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - | 
        cmake -S. -B build \
        -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug \
        -D BUILD_TESTS=ON \
        -D UPDATE_DEPS=ON \
        -D LOADER_ENABLE_ADDRESS_SANITIZER=ON \
        -D BUILD_WERROR=ON \
        -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++ \
        -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc && \
        cmake --build build
  - name: 'us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/github-test-builds-419921/ooctest/vulkan-loader-image:latest'
    entrypoint: '/bin/bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        ctest --output-on-failure --test-dir build/

  - name: 'us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/github-test-builds-419921/ooctest/vulkan-loader-image:latest'
    entrypoint: '/bin/bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        cmake --install build --prefix /tmp

  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
    args: ['-m', 'cp', '-r', '/tmp/lib', 'gs://test-ooc/${_ARTIFACT_NAME}/']
# This section is to specify artifacts to be stored
# artifacts:
#   objects:
#     location: 'gs://test-ooc/${_ARTIFACT_NAME}/'
#     paths:
#       - '/tmp/lib/**'
    
# Substitutions
options:
  automapSubstitutions: true
substitutions:
  _ARTIFACT_NAME: 'Vulkan-Loader-$SHORT_SHA'

The DockerFile used to build the image:
FROM ubuntu:22.04

# Avoid prompts from apt
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Update apt and install necessary packages
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y

RUN apt-get install -y \
    software-properties-common \
    ca-certificates \
    build-essential \
    libssl-dev \
    pkg-config \
    git \
    cmake

RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test

RUN apt update && \
    apt install --yes python3.7 python3.7-venv python3.7-dev && \
    apt install --yes clang

RUN python3.7 -m ensurepip
RUN python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN apt install --yes --no-install-recommends libwayland-dev libxrandr-dev && \
    sysctl vm.mmap_rnd_bits=28

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

The last build section and error from Google Cloud Build:
Step #1: 100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 555
Step #1: 
Step #1: Total Test time (real) =  55.32 sec
Finished Step #1
Starting Step #2
Step #2: Already have image (with digest): us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/github-test-builds-419921/ooctest/vulkan-loader-image:latest
Step #2: -- Install configuration: "Debug"
Step #2: -- Installing: /tmp/lib/libvulkan.so.1.3.280
Step #2: -- Installing: /tmp/lib/libvulkan.so.1
Step #2: -- Installing: /tmp/lib/libvulkan.so
Step #2: -- Installing: /tmp/lib/cmake/VulkanLoader/VulkanLoaderConfig.cmake
Step #2: -- Installing: /tmp/lib/cmake/VulkanLoader/VulkanLoaderConfig-debug.cmake
Step #2: -- Installing: /tmp/lib/cmake/VulkanLoader/VulkanLoaderConfigVersion.cmake
Step #2: -- Installing: /tmp/lib/pkgconfig/vulkan.pc
Finished Step #2
Starting Step #3
Step #3: Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
Step #3: CommandException: No URLs matched: /tmp/lib
Step #3: CommandException: 1 file/object could not be transferred.
Finished Step #3
ERROR
ERROR: build step 3 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1

If I create an Ubuntu 22.04 image on DigitalOcean and manually apply the DockerFile build steps and then pull the Vulkan-Loader test repository I made, and finally run through the cloudbuilder.yml steps manually, files are correctly generated in /tmp/lib. I've added some logging to the cloudbuild.yml file, and sure enough, there is no lib directory at /tmp/lib.
I've been searching for an answer, but now I need some help. Any suggestions what might be wrong, or how to fix this issue?

It seems that the issue may be related to the /tmp directory not being located or being cleared after each build step.
You can try this cloudbuild.yml file that includes a step to check if the /tmp directory exists:
steps:
  # Build configuration
  - name: 'us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/github-test-builds-419921/ooctest/vulkan-loader-image:latest'
    entrypoint: '/bin/bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - | 
        cmake -S. -B build \
        -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug \
        -D BUILD_TESTS=ON \
        -D UPDATE_DEPS=ON \
        -D LOADER_ENABLE_ADDRESS_SANITIZER=ON \
        -D BUILD_WERROR=ON \
        -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++ \
        -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc && \
        cmake --build build
  - name: 'us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/github-test-builds-419921/ooctest/vulkan-loader-image:latest'
    entrypoint: '/bin/bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        ctest --output-on-failure --test-dir build/

  - name: 'us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/github-test-builds-419921/ooctest/vulkan-loader-image:latest'
    entrypoint: '/bin/bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        cmake --install build --prefix /tmp

  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
    args: ['-m', 'ls', '-R', '/tmp']

  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
    args: ['-m', 'cp', '-r', '/tmp/lib', 'gs://test-ooc/${_ARTIFACT_NAME}/']
# This section is to specify artifacts to be stored
# artifacts:
#   objects:
#     location: 'gs://test-ooc/${_ARTIFACT_NAME}/'
#     paths:
#       - '/tmp/lib/**'
    
# Substitutions
options:
  automapSubstitutions: true
substitutions:
  _ARTIFACT_NAME: 'Vulkan-Loader-$SHORT_SHA'

Once you confirmed the issue is related with /tmp being cleared after each build step, then you can modify the build that installs Vulkan Loader to install it to a different directory that is not cleared after each build step.
You can try this build step:
- name: 'us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/github-test-builds-419921/ooctest/vulkan-loader-image:latest'
  entrypoint: '/bin/bash'
  args:
    - '-c'
    - |
      cmake --install build --prefix /usr/local

And then to copy the files to the Google Cloud Storage bucket:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
  args: ['-m', 'cp', '-r', '/usr/local/lib', 'gs://test-ooc/${_ARTIFACT_NAME}/']

